# Win32: IProgressDialog will not disappear until you mouse over it

Tags: winapi, message-queue

i'm using the [Win32 progress dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775248(VS.85).aspx). The damnest thing is that when i call:

```
progressDialog.StopProgressDialog();
```

it doesn't disappear. It stays on screen until the user moves her mouse over it - *then* it suddenly disappers.

The call to `StopProgressDialog` returns right away (i.e. it's not a synchronous call). i can prove this by doing things after the call has returned:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Force red background to prove we've started
   this.BackColor = Color.Red;
   this.Refresh();

   //Start a progress dialog
   IProgressDialog pd = (IProgressDialog)new ProgressDialog();
   pd.StartProgressDialog(this.Handle, null, PROGDLG.Normal, IntPtr.Zero);

   //The long running operation
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

   //Stop the progress dialog
   pd.SetLine(1, "Stopping Progress Dialog", false, IntPtr.Zero);
   pd.StopProgressDialog();
   pd = null;

   //Return form to normal color to prove we've stopped.
   this.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
   this.Refresh();
}
```

The form:

- starts gray
- turns red to show we've stared
- turns back to gray color to show we've called **stop**

So the call to `StopProgressDialog` has returned, except the progress dialog is still sitting there, mocking me, showing the message:

> Stopping Progress Dialog

[image]

---

### Doesn't Appear for 10 seconds

Additionally, the progress dialog does not appear on screen until the

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

ten second sleep is over.

---

### Not limited to .NET WinForms

The same code also fails in Delphi, which is also an object wrapper around Window's windows:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   pd: IProgressDialog;
begin
   Self.Color := clRed;
   Self.Repaint;

   pd := CoProgressDialog.Create;
   pd.StartProgressDialog(Self.Handle, nil, PROGDLG_NORMAL, nil);

   Sleep(10000);

   pd.SetLine(1, StringToOleStr('Stopping Progress Dialog'), False, nil);
   pd.StopProgressDialog;
   pd := nil;

   Self.Color := clBtnFace;
   Self.Repaint;
end;
```

---

### PreserveSig

An exception would be thrown if `StopProgressDialog` was failing.

*Most* of the methods in IProgressDialog, when translated into C# (or into Delphi), use the compiler's automatic mechanism of converting failed COM HRESULTS into a native language exception.

In other words the following two signatures will throw an exception if the COM call returned an error HRESULT (i.e. a value less than zero):

```
//C#
void StopProgressDialog();

//Delphi
procedure StopProgressDialog; safecall;
```

Whereas the following lets you see the HRESULT's and react yourself:

```
//C#
[PreserveSig]
int StopProgressDialog();

//Delphi
function StopProgressDialog: HRESULT; stdcall;
```

HRESULT is a 32-bit value. If the high-bit is set (or the value is negative) it is an error.

i am using the former syntax. So if `StopProgressDialog` is returning an error it will be automatically converted to a language exception.

**Note:** Just for SaG i used the `[PreserveSig]` syntax, the returned HRESULT is zero;

---

### MsgWait?

The symptom is similar to what [Raymond Chen described once](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/17/375307.aspx), which has to do with the incorrect use of PeekMessage followed by MsgWaitForMultipleObjects:

> "Sometimes my program gets stuck and
>   reports one fewer record than it
>   should. I have to jiggle the mouse to
>   get the value to update. After a while
>   longer, it falls two behind, then
>   three..."

But that would mean that the failure is in IProgressDialog, since it fails equally well on CLR .NET WinForms and native Win32 code.

Answer (score 4):

To really hide the dialog, I've added the following to my C++ wrapper class:

```
void CProgressDlg::Stop()
{
    if ((m_isVisible)&&(m_bValid))
    {
        HWND hDlgWnd = NULL;
        //Sometimes the progress dialog sticks around after stopping it,
        //until the mouse pointer is moved over it or some other triggers.
        //This process finds the hwnd of the progress dialog and hides it
        //immediately.
        IOleWindow *pOleWindow;
        HRESULT hr=m_pIDlg->QueryInterface(IID_IOleWindow,(LPVOID *)&pOleWindow);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr=pOleWindow->GetWindow(&hDlgWnd);
            if(FAILED(hr))
            {
                hDlgWnd = NULL;
            }
            pOleWindow->Release();
        }
        m_pIDlg->StopProgressDialog();
        if (hDlgWnd)
            ShowWindow(hDlgWnd, SW_HIDE);

        m_isVisible = false;
        m_pIDlg->Release();
        m_bValid = false;
    }
}
```

This is in C++, but you should be able to adapt this to C# without much problems.

Comment: This bug has been annoying me for a while now. Thanks for the answer Stefan.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of the  StopProgressDialog Method, maybe that will give you more information about what is going on:

> HRESULT StopProgressDialog(VOID);
>
> *Returns S_OK if successful, or an error value otherwise.*

Comment: i'm not using PreserveSig (or safecall for that matter)

Answer (score 0):

The full P/Invoke signature [is available](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IProgressDialog.html), but here's the condensed version for easy reading:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("EBBC7C04-315E-11d2-B62F-006097DF5BD4")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IProgressDialog
{
    void StartProgressDialog(IntPtr hwndParent,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]    object punkEnableModless, //IUnknown
        PROGDLG dwFlags,  //DWORD
        IntPtr pvResevered //LPCVOID
        );
    void StopProgressDialog();
    void SetTitle(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwzTitle //LPCWSTR
        );
    void SetAnimation(
        IntPtr hInstAnimation, //HINSTANCE
        ushort idAnimation //UINT
        );
    [PreserveSig]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    bool HasUserCancelled();
    void SetProgress(
        uint dwCompleted, //DWORD
        uint dwTotal //DWORD
        );
    void SetProgress64(
        ulong ullCompleted, //ULONGLONG
        ulong ullTotal //ULONGLONG
        );
    void SetLine(
        uint dwLineNum, //DWORD
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwzString, //LPCWSTR
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VariantBool)] bool fCompactPath, //BOOL
        IntPtr pvResevered //LPCVOID
        );
    void SetCancelMsg(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwzCancelMsg,
        object pvResevered
        );
    void Timer(PDTIMER dwTimerAction, object pvResevered);
}
```

**Note:** That almost all of the methods follow proper COM rules for their signatures. Except `HasUserCancelled`. It is does not follow the rules for the signature of a method in a COM class. All methods are supposed to return an **HRESULT**, and return values are supposed to be in an `out retval` paramater. **HasUserCancelled** actually returns a Boolean value.

**Note:** That almost all these worlds are yours. Except `Europa`. Attempt no landing there.

**Note:** That almost all your base are belong to us. Except `WhatYouSay`. Main light turn on.